# Perform a clean submit by removing hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform a 'clean' submit, i.e. a submit that is invoked after removing all hidden divs from the form field.

Since this is a feature I am going to use more often, I shifted my code into the extend-part:

```
$.fn.extend({   
  bindCleanSubmit: function() {
    $(this).submit( function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).find("div:hidden").remove();
      console.log("trying to commit...");

      return true;
    });
  }
});
```

Now, all divs are removed, the console event is triggered but at the end the submit has not performed.

Do you now the problem here?

Comment: I don't understand what the point of removing the divs is in the first place.

Comment: event.preventDefault();
will prevent the submission. So you will have to submit the form in your function

Comment: Great question, I think John Rumpel is trying to remove hidden fields under those divs, so they don't submit to db.

Comment: @Yeronimo: Rather remove `event.preventDefault()`. If you trigger the submit event again, this handler would be called again as well.

Comment: @FelixKling Not if you trigger it with `$(theform)[0].submit()` (or obviously `theform.submit()`), but in this case it makes sense to just not prevent default.

Comment: @KevinB: Right! Still, removing that statement seems to make more sense to me. *edit:* yep :)

Comment: `$(this).submit(` is redundant, `this` is already a jQuery object, just do `this.submit(`

Comment: You are right. thought I would call that function to prevent from invoking submit before executing the following code.

Comment: No worries, the form doesn't get submitted before the handler was executed. After all, the return value of the handler determines whether the form is submitted or not, so the browser has to wait until the handler returns.

Comment: @FelixKling I have a feeling the hidden form fields are inside of the hidden divs so he is removing the divs

Comment: @Huangism: I think you are right, it just isn't very clear from the question.

Comment: @FelixKling definitely not, the only reason I can think of for removing the div is they have hidden fields within it

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `preventDefault()`, but if you remove it from `bindCleanSubmit()`, hidden divs will be removed from the form and it will be submitted normally. So given the following html:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="displayedInput" value="1"/>
    <div style="display: none">
        <input type="text" name="hiddenInput" value="1"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

...and the updated plugin:

```
$.fn.extend({   
  bindCleanSubmit: function() {
    $(this).submit( function(event) {
      $(this).find("div:hidden").remove();
      console.log("trying to commit...");
      return true;
    });
  }
}); 

$('#myform').bindCleanSubmit();
```

...only the `displayedInput` value will be submitted to the server when `myform` is submitted.